# Significance test for average profit per user

Tags: statistical-significance, ab-test

I'm going to be running an A/B test trying out two different prices for a product. I'm interested the average profit per user for the two variants.

Since most people won't convert, I will have samples that contain many zeros, and some larger values for users who converted. The non-zero values will likely be one of a few possible values.

My question is, how would I go about conducting a single-tail significance test for such skewed data?

Comment: Are you familiar with zero-inflated regression? These are an option for generalized additive models

Comment: I will dig into that, thanks for the reply!